# Request for Rui Li twitter dataset

Tags: dataset, share

I have searched the web for long time looking for Rui Li twitter dataset named **"Dataset-UDI-TwitterCrawl-Aug2012"**. I have tried all the Illinois university hyperlinks provided for the dataset, but all of them are not working.

I expect that any one who has it can share it with me.